# Incorrectly highlighted code errors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, syntax-error, resharper, syntax-highlighting

I have just opened a solution that builds with no errors, but nearly every line of code, in every class, in every project, shows keywords, type, and method names in red, as if none at all of the referenced assemblies are present. E.g:

[image]

When I first open the solution, everything appears fine, and then a few seconds later, everything looks like this.

I am using VS 2015 Update 3 with ReSharper Ultimate 2016.2. I have a host of other little extensions, but , as far as I know, nothing knew, and I have only experienced this problem temporarily before, e.g. only on the first time I open the solution.

I have just repaired ReSharper with no change, but have deferred the lengthy VS repair process to first see if I can find anything out.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the ReSharper caches? (`ReSharper`->`Options...`->`Environment`->`General` and click the `Clear caches` button)

Comment: Thank you, I've never noticed that, and it worked fine. Answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing the ReSharper caches will usually help this kind of issue. (`ReSharper`->`Options...`->`Environment`->`General` and click the `Clear caches` button)

[image]